# Does there exist a non-finite subset X of $\Bbb Q^2$ such that every real valued continuous function on X is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I think so.

Because if we think of a non-finite subset X of $\Bbb Q$ such that every real valued continuous function on X is bounded. We can take X to be $\{1/n\} \cup\{0\}$. Since the function is continuous at 0, it is bounded around $0$. And the set of all other points is finite, so it is bounded.

In a similar manner we can do for $\Bbb Q^2$ .

Is my proof okay?
If not please explain or give a simple proof

Comment: This seems correct to me.

Comment: alternatively, take any infinite, compact subset $X$ of $\mathbb{Q}^2$. real valued continuous functions on compact sets attain maximums and minimums, and are hence bounded.